# telebot delete message pytelegrambotapi

Tags: telegram, message, py-telegram-bot-api, telebot

How can I delete the last N number of messages from any users. After writing the delete command, the bot must delete the latest messages by the given number. I could not find complete documentation on the pytelegrambotapi library in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience you should save the `message_id` of  the lasts N messagges and cycling with the `delete_message` function when you need to do it.

```
bot = telegram.Bot(token=TOKEN)


message_ids = {}

message_id = bot.send_message(chat_id, text).message_id

if chat_id in message_ids.keys():
  message_ids[chat_id].append(message_id)
else:
  message_ids[chat_id] = [message_id]
```

When you need to delete the messages from some chat you can do (remember that messages after 48h aren't possible to be deleted)

```
for message_id in message_ids[chat_id]:
   bot.delete_message(chat_id, message_id)
```

I'm sure it's perfectible, but I think it's a good basic idea

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but I did not understand what parameter is `chat_id` you meant `message.chat.id`?

Comment: Yes I mean that :)